# SQL Server database in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to understand the difference between SQL Server database (`.mdf` files) and Local database file (`.sdf`).

I couldn't find local database item in Visual Studio 2019 to add to Windows Forms C# application.

How can I add Local DB to Visual Studio 2019?

[image]

Comment: `.sdf` files are SQL Server **Compact Edition** database files; but SQL Server Compact Edition (SQL Server CE) has been discontinued quite a while ago, and is no longer supported - that's probably why you can't find support for it in VS2019 (and probably won't be able to retrofit it into VS 2019, either)

Comment: If you really want to use a local DB, you can use that option `Service-based Database` but you need to install at least one SQL Server instance to be able to use that

Comment: If you want to use SQL Compact with VS 2019, you can use SQL Server Compact Toolbox

Comment: I will use Service-based-Database